# Powershell - Invoke-Command with multiple functions and ArgumentList

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I create something like this in powershell in the right way?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $i -ScriptBlock ${function1 , function2} -credential $cred -ArgumentList parameter_function1,parameter_function1,parameter_function_2
```

Comment: Take a look at Invoke-Command [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6), the examples should help

Comment: As an aside: A _script-block literal_ has the form  `{ ... }`. `${...}` is only ever used to reference _variables_ (unambiguously), where the `...` is the variable's _name_.

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case, rely on the **automatic `$args` variable**, which contains the array of (undeclared) arguments:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $i -ScriptBlock {
  function1 $args[0]
  function2 $args[1]
} -credential $cred -ArgumentList arg_function1, arg_function2
```

As in any script block (`{ ... }`) **you can *explicitly declare* parameters** (and optionally declare their *type*, and add *attributes* - see [about_functions_advanced_parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters)), using `param(...)`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $i -ScriptBlock {
  param($foo, $bar)
  function1 $foo
  function2 $bar
} -credential $cred -ArgumentList arg_function1, arg_function2
```